# Conditional closures in Julia

Tags: julia

In many applications of map(f,X), it helps to create closures that depending on parameters apply different functions f to data X.

I can think of at least the following three ways to do this (note that the second for some reason does not work, bug?)

```
f0(x,y) = x+y
f1(x,y,p) = x+y^p

function g0(power::Bool,X,y)
  if power
    f = x -> f1(x,y,2.0)
  else
    f = x -> f0(x,y)
  end
  map(f,X)
end

function g1(power::Bool,X,y)
  if power
    f(x) = f1(x,y,2.0)
  else
    f(x) = f0(x,y)
  end
  map(f,X)
end

abstract FunType
abstract PowerFun <: FunType
abstract NoPowerFun <: FunType

function g2{S<:FunType}(T::Type{S},X,y)
  f(::Type{PowerFun},x) = f1(x,y,2.0)
  f(::Type{NoPowerFun},x) = f0(x,y)
  map(x -> f(T,x),X)
end

X = 1.0:1000000.0

burnin0 = g0(true,X,4.0) + g0(false,X,4.0);
burnin1 = g1(true,X,4.0) + g1(false,X,4.0);
burnin2 = g2(PowerFun,X,4.0) + g2(NoPowerFun,X,4.0);

@time r0true = g0(true,X,4.0); #0.019515 seconds (12 allocations: 7.630 MB)
@time r0false = g0(false,X,4.0); #0.002984 seconds (12 allocations: 7.630 MB)

@time r1true = g1(true,X,4.0); # 0.004517 seconds (8 allocations: 7.630 MB, 26.28% gc time)
@time r1false = g1(false,X,4.0); # UndefVarError: f not defined

@time r2true = g2(PowerFun,X,4.0); # 0.085673 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 38.147 MB, 3.90% gc time)
@time r2false = g2(NoPowerFun,X,4.0); # 0.234087 seconds (2.00 M allocations: 38.147 MB, 60.61% gc time)
```

What is the optimal way to do this in Julia?

Comment: Try `burning0 = f1.(X, 4.0, 2.0) + f0.(X, 4.0)`

Comment: Btw you'd better use `const X = 1.0:1000000.0`

Comment: No need for `const` since he's passing it as a function argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no need to use map here at all. Using a closure doesn't make things simpler or faster. Just use ["dot-broadcasting"](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/functions/#dot-syntax-for-vectorizing-functions) to apply the functions directly:

```
function g3(X,y,power=1)
  if power != 1
    return f1.(X, y, power) # or simply X .+ y^power
  else
    return f0.(X, y) # or simply X .+ y
  end
end
```